# Por que não posso conectar ao meu servidor MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Eu estou tentando fazer uma consulta simples usando um webservice PHP. Este é o meu código atual:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://192.168.0.2/executeQuery.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
```

E esta é executeQuery.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Tem alguma coisa errada? Embora meu servidor está funcionando bem mais acesso direto ao executeQuery.php, estou recebendo essa exceção:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.2 refused
Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: O erro mostrado não é do servidor MySQL não conectando, e sim do servidor da aplicação PHP que não está respondendo. Como você está rodando a aplicação PHP? Você consegue acessar ela no browser usando o endereço `http://192.168.0.2`?

Answer (score 2):

Pela mensagem de erro de conexão recusada, dá para deduzir que o servidor Web do PHP não está respondendo na porta 80 do endereço 192.168.0.2. Muito provavelmente o endereço IP ou a porta não são os certos. O IP não seria 192.168.1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, em primeiro lugar recomendo fortemente a não utilização da biblioteca mysql_*, pois logo em breve sera descontinuada (deprecated), para tanto existe algumas alternativas muito mais seguras inclusive.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

http://medoo.in/ Eu utilizo essa ultima, pois já tem proteções bem rígidas contra SQL Injection e uma biblioteca bem ampla, no entanto requer a versão do php 5.4+ (por conta da mudança de sintax em relação ao array)

OBS: As duas ultimas roda por baixo a mysqli, sendo esta a mais rápida se sua aplicação visa alto desempenho.

Chega de tanto blabla e vamos ao exemplo pratico.
O mysqli permite a escrita de duas formas diferente.

Resolvi estrutal como você esta fazendo:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente modificar o seu código e colocar esse, caso não funcione o select, acedito que o seu campo id seja um inteiro então pode remover as aspas simples, e também adicionei um link para identificar a conexão.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password")or die("Erro ao conectar com o servidor de dados");
mysql_select_db("database",$link)or die("Erro ao selecionar base de dados");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$_REQUEST['id'],$link);
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```